# Cut points of monotonicity of data including date duration or line naming

Tags: r

I have this dataset

```
date1<-c(rep(c("2020-06-01"),times=20))
date2<-c(rep(c("2020-06-02"),times=15))
date3<-c(rep(c("2020-06-03"),times=5))
date4<-c(rep(c("2020-06-04"),times=10))
date5<-c(rep(c("2020-06-05"),times=2))
date<-c(date1,date2,date3,date4,date5)
x<-c(52,52,51,51,51,51,50,50,50,49,49,49,49,48,48,50,60,70,80,90,100,100,100,100,100,100,99,98,98,95,94,80,70,60,70,80,90,100,100,100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10,70,90,10)
y<-c(rep(c(30),times=51))
y<-c(NA,y)
data <- data.frame(date,x, y)
```

And I would like to have the sum of y variable where x variable appears to have cut points (increase/decrease) among with the date duration or better the names of the lines the monotonicity of values appears (increase/decrease)

Well I tried this code which works perfectly fine and gives me the cut points and sums them

```
date <- as.Date(data$date,format="%Y-%m-%d")
d <- c(0, diff(data$x))
d[d==0] <- NA
d <- zoo::na.locf(zoo::na.locf(d, na.rm = FALSE), na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = TRUE)
f <- cumsum(abs(c(0, diff(d <= 0))))
tapply(data$y, f, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
unname(tapply(data$y, f, sum, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Which gives me this result

```
[1] 420 330 240 180 270  60  30
```

Despite this works fine I wanna know more about the date or duration or better the name of the lines where x values increase/decrease

The preferred output would be

```
[ ] 1:15 16:26 27:34  35:40   41:49  50:51  52
[1] 420  330   240    180     270    60     30
```

Answer (score 1):

If data and f are as in the question then:

```
ysum <- tapply(data$y, f, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
Rng <- function(x) { 
  rng <- range(x)
  if (rng[1] == rng[2]) rng[1] else paste(rng[1], rng[2], sep = ":") 
}
result <- setNames(ysum, tapply(seq_along(f), f, Rng))
result
## 1:15 16:26 27:34 35:40 41:49 50:51    52 
##  420   330   240   180   270    60    30
```

Comment: That looks great it works!!! If i want to split this on the increased and decreased? I tried this splitted<-split(setNames(tt, tapply(seq_along(f), f, Rng)),f=1:2)
 but it does't work

Comment: Assuming you want to split the sums that have increased vs. decreased from the prior sum, try `split(result, c(1, diff(result)) > 0)` where `result` is defined in t he answer.  Have assumed that the first sum goes into the increased component of the split..

Comment: I don't think this is right i want something like a column with the decreased values along with the lines and a column with the decreased values along with the lines too. The decreased col will be 420, 240,270,30 along with the lines and the increased col the rest.

Comment: the sums are  420   330   240   180   270    60    30  so being first 420 is arbitrary so it was put it into the increased component (but you can change 1 to 0 to force it into decreased)  and of the rest only 270 is larger than the prior sum.